# Raster resampling using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, resampling

I am trying to apply resampling to Rasters generated from an nc file, rendered using PyQGIS in my Python application. Used QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer() for it. I could use resampling in the QGIS GUI in the layer styling panel, but I am looking for a way to do it programmatically through Python. I came across the following functions in the QGIS docs. However they do not seem to work.

Am I missing something?

```
 raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(input_nc_filename, region)
 resampleFilter = raster_layer.resampleFilter()
 resampleFilter.setZoomedInResampler(QgsBilinearRasterResampler())
 resampleFilter.setZoomedOutResampler(QgsBilinearRasterResampler())
```

Also came across [rasterResamplerV2](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Raster/QgsRasterResampler.html#qgis.core.QgsRasterResampler.resample) in the docs, but could not find an example as to how the interface methods must be used.

Comment: How do you define `raster_layer`? Your code is working for me. You need to switch tab for the changes it to show. Go to transparency tab then back to symbology

Comment: raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(input_nc_filename, region)

 It works for me as well with the GUI. But not throught the python code. The .tiff file that gets generated looks the same(i.e pixelated) with or without this code @BERA

Comment: I am facing issues with gdal installation, is there no other alternative to warp?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.